# Like a Pollock am I

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Like a Pollock am I
> Alongside never, forever and reality I lie
> With a small twist I am an excuse
> Without said twist I am no use
> If these clues make your answers fall short
> A hint most deserved will aid your effort

Identify me.

Hint 1:

> I'm sorry, my friend, but we will never meet;
> I must exist without you and you without me

Hint 2:

> Now that we're onto the topic of 'to be'
> I'll add that my name itself defies me

Hint 3:

> My antonyms can be any
> And all in all are a lot
> My synonyms are not many
> I tell you, zilch, nada, squat

Reasoning for answer (SPOILER)

> Jackson Pollock is an abstract artist and 'never', 'forever' and 'reality' are abstract concepts
> An example of an excuse through a linguistic twist: 'What are you up to?' 'Nothing.'
> When taken literally, nothing is, well, good for nothing.
> We can never meet nothing because as soon as we exist, nothingness doesn't.
> A name is a thing - a word is a thing. Therefore, naming it or identifying it in any way renders 'nothing' nonexistent.
> Synonyms and antonyms are obvious, there's a reason that was my giveaway hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you:

> **Nothing**

Because:
Like a Pollock am I

> Jackson Pollock's paintings look like *nothing* to the untrained eye.

Alongside never, forever and reality I lie

> "*nothing*" is a concept similar to those above.

With a small twist I am an excuse

> "*nothing* to do with me!" (or similar)

Without said twist I am no use

> "*nothing*" is not very useful

Hint one:

> you can't meet *nothing* and must exist without *nothing*.

Hint two:

> If you give a name to *nothing*, it becomes something, so it stops being *nothing*.

Hint three:

> Most things are something, so they would be antonyms of nothing, and *zilch, nada, squat* are examples of the few synonyms that *nothing* has.

Comment: @kanoo changed answer

Comment: You have the correct answer. I will add my reasoning to my question (in spoilers of course) - you got most of it, your reasoning just differs from mine in the Pollock line and hint one

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> The word 'not'?

*Like a Pollock am I*

> A quick google suggests that "not Pollock" is a thing

*Alongside never, forever and reality I lie*

> Doesn't fit perfectly here, but the words are abstract concepts

With a small twist I am an excuse

> 'not' becomes "can not" or "will not", which are excuses

Without said twist I am no use

> a 'knot' without the twist used to tie the knot is of no use

First Clue:

> Alludes to the idea of one existing without the other, which is what the 'not' operator (usually '!') means in mathematics and programming

Second Clue:

> "To be or not to be" is what sent me down this path, and that a name of 'not' is self-defiant because "not not" is a double negative, which becomes a positive

Comment: You are very close!

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> A *red herring*?

Like a Pollock am I

> A *real* herring is a sea fish, like the pollock.

I'm sorry, my friend, but we will never meet

> A "red herring" is a figurative expression referring to a logical fallacy. So you won't ever "meet" a red herring because it doesn't exist. Most of your clues seem to imply abstract concepts.

Comment: Yes, most of my clues do imply abstract concepts. Try a different path with Pollock (although it seems that you've gotten where I was going with that anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but this fits for some of the clues:

> Jackson

Like a Pollock am I

> Jackson Pollock the famous painter.

Alongside never, forever and reality I lie

> There is another famous Jackson with the last name Galaxy that could fit this.

With a small twist I am an excuse

> If you change the j to a b you would have 'back son' which could suggest your back hurt and be an excuse

Without said twist I am no use

> I someone said you have 'Jack son' then you have nothing which would be of no use.

Comment: Nice try, sometimes along the right track. But no